# PHP array from function

Tags: php, arrays

In trying to pass an array function from one php page to another. page try.php has the actual function

```
function someFunc() {

include_once("includes/dbconnect.php");
$types = array();
$connect = TRUE;
$dbconn = dbconnect($connect);

if ($dbconn) {
    $sql = "select usertype, userdeptnum from bd.bdusers";

    $stmt = db2_prepare($dbconn, $sql);
    if ($stmt) {
        $result = db2_execute($stmt);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "exec errormsg: " . db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
        }

        while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
            $types[] = $row;

        }
    } else {
        echo "exec errormsg: " . db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
    }
    db2_close($dbconn);
} else {
    echo "faild " . db2_conn_errormsg();
}

return array($types);
}
```

If i use

```
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($types);
 echo "</pre>";
```

i get this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 1
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 1
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 2
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 28
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 1
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 28
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 2
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 3
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 1
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 1
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 1
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 1
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 2
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 3
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 1
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 31
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 2
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 2
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 2
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 1
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 2
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 56
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 2
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 89
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 2
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 56
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 2
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 45
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [USERTYPE] => 2
        [USERDEPTNUM] => 90
    )

)
```

But when I pass this function on try2.php and so the same pre, print_r to see what I get I get this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 1
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 1
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 5
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 2
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 28
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 1
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 28
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 2
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 3
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 1
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 1
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 1
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 1
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 2
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 3
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 1
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 31
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 2
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 2
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 2
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 1
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 2
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 56
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 2
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 89
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 2
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 56
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 2
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 45
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [USERTYPE] => 2
                [USERDEPTNUM] => 90
            )

    )

)
```

It's an array inside an array. Ive tried to echo out the array using foreach, and with a for loop, but I alway get undefined index or Array to string conversion and its just prints out "Array".
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Because you returned `array($types);`. Return `$types` instead of `array($types)`.

```
function someFunc() {
    include_once("includes/dbconnect.php");
    $types = array();
    $connect = TRUE;
    $dbconn = dbconnect($connect);
    if ($dbconn) {
        $sql = "select usertype, userdeptnum from bd.bdusers";
        $stmt = db2_prepare($dbconn, $sql);
        if ($stmt) {
            $result = db2_execute($stmt);
            if (!$result) {
                echo "exec errormsg: " . db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
            }
            while ($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
                $types[] = $row;

            }
        } else {
        echo "exec errormsg: " . db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
    }
    db2_close($dbconn);
    } else {
        echo "faild " . db2_conn_errormsg();
    }
    return $types; //<==
}
```

**EDIT :**
In `try.php` try this code to show result in table

```
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><th>USERTYPE</th><th>USERDEPTNUM</th></tr>';
foreach($types as $val){
    echo '<tr><td>'.$val['USERTYPE'].'</td><td>'.$val['USERDEPTNUM'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I changed that one line and refreshed try2.php and with pre I get the correct looking array but the foreach gives me this error "Notice: Array to string conversion in /www/websvr6/try2.php on line 17
Array" What i'm trying to do is populate a table with this array. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include_once("try.php");


$types = someFunc();

echo "<pre>";
print_r(someFunc());
echo "</pre>";

foreach ($types as $list){
echo $types;

}
?>
```